# AgChartsReact Zoom feature is not working

Tags: ag-charts-react, ag-charts

I was using AgChartsReact from ag-charts-react library 9.0.0 version to generate a line chart. I have configured the options as below.

```
{
          data: chartData,
          autoSize: true,
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
          },
          zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            enableScrolling: true
          },
          series: [
            {
              type: 'line',
              xKey: 'key',
              xName: 'Key',
              yKey: 'previousValue',
              yName: 'Previous Value',
              stroke: 'red',
              marker: {
                fill: 'red',
              },
              highlightStyle: {
                series: {
                  strokeWidth: 3,
                  dimOpacity: 0.2,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              type: 'line',
              xKey: 'key',
              xName: 'Key',
              yKey: 'currentValue',
              yName: 'Current Value',
              stroke: 'green',
              marker: {
                fill: 'green',
              },
              highlightStyle: {
                series: {
                  strokeWidth: 3,
                  dimOpacity: 0.5,
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          theme: {
            baseTheme: 'ag-default',
            overrides: {
              line: {
                series: {
                  highlightStyle: {
                    series: {
                      strokeWidth: 3,
                      dimOpacity: 0.2,
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
          navigator: {
            enabled: true,
            min: props.minNavigator,
            max: props.maxNavigator,
          },
          overlays: {
            noData: {
              text: 'No data to display',
            },
          },
        }
```

Even though I have enabled zoom feature as suggested in community portal, I don't see it working.

https://charts.ag-grid.com/react/zoom/

Can someone suggest what was the mistake in this config.

Answer (score 1):

Αccording to documentation in charts ag-grid website, to use zoom feature you must ensure that navigator feature is disabled.

Check angular related documentation in https://charts.ag-grid.com/angular/zoom/#navigator

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).